# Avoiding automatic conversion of dgCMatrix to dgeMatrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I use the class `dgCMatrix` from the `Matrix` package to store a square matrix of about 255 million values, with a size of about 1.7MB .

However after I perform `variable <- variable/rowSums(variable)` where `variable` is the sparse matrix, the resulting variable changes into class `dgeMatrix`, and the size ballooned to almost 2GB, effectively taking up all memory available and in some instances crashing the script.

Is there a way to coerce the output to remain in the class `dgCMatrix` ?

I suspect that the reason is that the number of non-zero elements increase to the point that the matrix is no longer considered sparse, due to introduction of NaN in elements where the sum of rows is zero. If there's a work around to address the NaN 's , I'm open to that too. Note however that I cannot avoid producing the zero rows, because my matrix need to be a square, and the corresponding column sums are generally non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing a simple ifelse function for the divisor:

```
variable <- variable/ifelse(rowSums(variable)!=0,rowSums(variable),1)
```

Unless there's some reason you need to be dividing by the 0 there, that seems like the simplest way to avoid NANs.

Comment: Thanks, this is nifty and works; I wish I had thought of this earlier.

I'll leave the question open for a while as I am still interested if there is a way to coerce to `dgCMatrix` as I foresee I may need for another scenario. If no such solution exists, I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This is the work-around that I am using to avoid NaNs and to preserve the output in the class `dgCMatrix`:

```
tmp = 1/rowSums(variable)
tmp[is.infinite(tmp)] <- 0
variable <- variable * tmp
```